# Carbon capture and liquid air energy storage - a single system?

Tags: thermodynamics, gas, energy-storage

I've noticed these [liquid air energy storage projects](http://energystorage.org/energy-storage/technologies/liquid-air-energy-storage-laes).

As the process consists of phase changes between air and liquid I was wondering if it would be possible to extract CO2 as part of this process?

From  what I understand oxygen, nitrogen and carbon dioxide all liquefy and boil at different temperatures and pressures. Would it therefore be feasible to control either the liquification or boiling so that you could capture the carbon dioxide at one of these stages?

This would obviously result in a loss of efficiency in the system but if it could become both an energy storage and carbon capture system then maybe it would be more efficient than having two separate systems for that?

Apologies I am not a scientist of any description and have only a rudimentary understanding of these things.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. CO2 could definitely be removed in the process of compressing and cooling the air. Other valuable products like Argon could also be removed. That is exactly how gas distillation companies like Airgas [separate different gasses from the air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_separation) for use in welding, medical, etc.

Conversely, if a feasible pressurized [carbon sequestration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_sequestration) exists, you could just as easily couple it with a gas distillation plant like Airgas. These companies are [very common](https://www.mathesongas.com/gases/bulk/air-separation-plants) and already economically viable. It would also work as a separate business model, by just simply purchasing the pressurized CO2.